# ZXing QR scanner unable to run after 2nd time running from phone

Tags: java, android-studio, qr-code, barcode-scanner

i am facing some problem with the QR scanner. I am using the ZXing library.

When i run the app from android studio to my device, i am able to open the QR scanner and can scan the QR code after clicking the "QR Scanner" button, however after i close the app from my device and reopening the app directly from my device itself, the scanner does not work. It shows a blank screen instead of the camera screen.

I have already imported the permission for camera and the library that i am using is **compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'**

Can anyone help me and tell me how i am suppose to let it run everytime when i open the app from my device?  Thankssss

**This is my code for the QR scanner**

```
public void QrScanner(View view){
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
    setContentView(mScannerView);
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
    mScannerView.startCamera();         // Start camera
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    // Do something with the result here
    Log.v("handleResult", rawResult.getText());
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setMessage(rawResult.getText());
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into a similar problem. Try stopCamera() in onDestroy() like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}
```